# Using an argv argument at the end of a string match

Tags: python, pandas, argparse, argv

I am doing a relatively simple task of taking strings within a dataframe column, and using those strings to fill a new column.

First I create a new column, and then fill it with the updated Book name based off the string that it finds in the column 'Book Name' in the dataframe. I need to match the exact string including year and quarter.

My old code is:

```
#Create empty column to map book names to

datagrouped["Book"] = ""

#Map book names by exact string matching the old values    

data['Book'][df['Book Name'] == America [Q3 2018]'] = North America 
data['Book'][df['Book Name'] == International [Q3 2018]'] = Intl 
data['Book'][df['Book Name'] == Asia [Q3 2018]'] = APAC
```

Ideally I would like to use argv, as I am running this from the command line. I am already using an argv earlier in the code to read in the CSV file, and it works. My question is, how would I modify this to accept another argv (sys.argv[2]) so that I can put the year and quarter as an argument in the command line? So far I have tried

```
quarter = sys.argv[2] 

datagrouped["Book"] = ""

data['Book'][df['Book Name'] == America + str.quarter] = North America 
data['Book'][df['Book Name'] == International + str.quarter] = Intl
data['Book'][df['Book Name'] == Asia + str.quarter] = APAC
```

If there is anything that I can add to this question, please do let me know and I will update it.

Comment: If you call your module adding one more argument it will be put in `argv[2]`, so just use your `quarter` variable as you defined it.

Comment: @toti08 do you mean remove the str. before quarter? I tried that and it gives me a syntax error. Sorry if I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't understand that. Could you please add the complete traceback to your question? Also what are `International`, `Asia` and 'America`? If you want to convert `quarter` to string you should use `str(quarter)`.

Comment: What do you intend `str.quarter` to do or be?  It doesn't make sense.  You have created a variable called `quarter`.  `str` is a function.  It doesn't have a `quarter` attribute or method.  For a simple commandline processing, just treat `sys.argv` as a list of strings.  While debugging, print it so have a clear idea of what's in that list.  No guessing!